# Как получить данные с другого компонента

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Добрый день. Имеется несколько компонентов, в которых есть массив данных(название, цена). Все они подключаются через главный компонент. Как мне можно получить сумму цен всех выбранных элементов со всех компонентов?

Comment: Как, как.. Для каждого компонента взять сумму всех цен, потом просуммировать по всем компонентам. Добавьте свой образец кода, иначе трудно что-то советовать кроме таких банальных вещей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На счёт взаимодействия в Vue.js позиция проста: Потомки шлют события, предки передают данные "вниз".
Ну как-то так:

```js
Vue.component('Price', {
  template: `
<div class="priceWrapper">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="state" @click="handler" /> Цена: $\{{price}}
  </label>
</div>`,
  data: function(){
    return {
      state: false,
      price: Math.floor(Math.random() * (500 - 1 + 1)) + 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handler: function(){
      // Изменение чекбокса вызывает эмит данных для предка
      this.$parent.$emit('change', this.price, this.state);
    }
  }
});


new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    total: 0
  },
  created(){
    // Слушаем события от потомков
    // Получаем цену и состояние чекбокса
    this.$on('change', function(price, state){
      this.total = state ? this.total + price : this.total - price;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <Price></Price>
  <Price></Price>
  <Price></Price>
  <Price></Price>
  <Price></Price>
  <Price></Price>
  <Price></Price>
  <Price></Price>
  <Price></Price>
  <Price></Price>
  <Price></Price>
  <Price></Price>
  <span>Общая цена: <strong>${{total}}</strong></span>
</div>
```